# Full-sized columns with floated content?

Tags: html, css

My site is up here:

[Green McP](http://www.greenmcp.com/index.php?/projects/)

I'm trying to put my old WP powered site into Expression Engine (just for giggles), and I'm stuck with my project layout: I want a grid of my projects, each a div with a set height/width. If I don't float them left, they just stack vertically. If I do float them left, they arrange themselves as I want, but the #column in the background loses its height and thus the BG. It's possible to make it bigger with min-height: 700px, but that won't work in IE as I'm told. What's another way to get things into grids (w/o tables, preferably).

Thanks!

Comment: You should get that site checked in webkit based browsers - the layout appears broken in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Keith do you mean broken in addition to the problem I stated, that the main column BG doesn't go all the way down? What is else is wrong? I'm in Safari on Mac OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clear the floats.

You can add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#column` container.

For more information and details about 'clearfix' check out: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do one of these:

- Make #column float left as well; or
- Set `overflow: auto` to #column